# for loop accessing list

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I have a list of the form "myfiles([f('a',2,1),f('h',6,'o'),f('a','w',0)])"

I need to print ''' "We have in our    file:\nf('a',2,1)\nf('h',6,0)\nf('a','w',0)\n" '''

code:

```
def check_files(allfiles):
    strg = 'We have in our file:\n'
    for item in allfiles:
        strg += (item+\n)
    print (strg)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do i access the list? "myfiles([.....]) , i get an error 'item' or 'object' not iterable!

Comment: I'm guessing `myfiles()` is a function. Does it return a list?

Comment: The output should be a string: ''' "We have in our file:\nf('a',2,1)\nf('h',6,0)\nf('a','w',0)\n" '''

Comment: I am trying to access it through the loop, and output the content in string form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not inputting a list into your function `check_files()`. What you refer to as a list is not actually a list. It looks like a function call to `myfiles()`. In any case, you need to input an actual list into your function. You also have to change `\n` to `'\n'`.

```
list_ = ["f('a',2,1)", "f('h',6,'o')", "f('a','w',0)"]

def check_files(allfiles):
    strg = 'We have in our file:\n'
    for item in allfiles:
        strg += item + '\n'
    return strg
```

And here you can see the output.

```
>>> print check_files(list_)
We have in our file:
f('a',2,1)
f('h',6,'o')
f('a','w',0)
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the list inside the function myfiles([....])??? In my exercise it's given in that form. Thanks

Comment: For your exercise, are you given `"myfiles([f('a',2,1),f('h',6,'o'),f('a','w',0)])"`? If so, you are given a string.

Comment: Correct. But how do I print the string in the format above??

Comment: I won't write the code for you, but try to use string splitting.